# What do I do with the tomato blocks?

Tags: kirby-return-to-dreamland

I found a red block that has a picture of a tomato on it. Normally, tomatoes fill my health meter, so I was kind of hoping that somehow I could get a tomato out of the block.

I tried sucking it up, and nothing happened. I tried throwing it at someone, and nothing happened. I also tried burning it and cutting it (those were the two other moves available to me at the time) with no results.

What do I do with this block? Am I ever going to get a yummy, juicy tomato out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside you'll find an **Maxim Tomato**.  But you need to let it open up for you to get what's inside.  After you pick it up and drop it, it will eventually open.  It won't open while you're holding it.

It doesn't open up immediately that way you can take it with you as far as you can.  Particularly useful if you are playing multi-player and think you might need it later.  One of you could pick it up and carry it with you until someone needs it.

Comment: Ah, that explains why I found it right before a mini-boss fight. So I pick it up, drop it and wait? Or drop it more than once?

Comment: If you want the tomato that's inside, just drop it and wait.  It will burst open and you can pick the tomato up.  Otherwise if you don't want it to open yet, make sure you're holding it at all times or it will.

Comment: Ah, okay, that clears that up. Good to know. :)

Comment: It also won't open if you press `Down+1` to set it down, which lets you put it down, beat stuff up, and pick it back up to take elsewhere.